# use the comparison result as the index of pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,np.nan,6]])
whereNans = np.isnan(df)
print whereNans
print df[whereNans]

print "--"*30

print df>3
print df[df>3]
```

As above, `whereNans` is correct, but `df[whereNans]` doesn't get what I want. However, `df[df>3]` can get what I want.

Actually, the index stored in `whereNans` is same as the `df>3`. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `df[df.isnull()]`? Using numpy loses any information about the index.

Comment: @IanS this has nothing to do with this, it's just slightly confusing because the OP is trying to mask `NaN` values, so where the mask is True it returns NaN where it's False it also returns NaN, if the column and index values were not plain int indices then yes this would happen as it becomes a reindex operation

Comment: Thanks @EdChum I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @IanS thanks, and don't think my comment is any form of attack, it's not immediately apparent the behaviour here

Comment: @IanS yes the last comment was directed at OP, I didn't do `@`, I think SO auto forwards the comment to the last poster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused by this, this is correct behaviour, where the mask is `True` it will display the result in that position, where `False` it will display `NaN`, so in effect you're going to display a df with all `NaN`s

Because you have a single `NaN` value it returns `NaN` for that position, where it's False you just get `NaN`

If you compare with `df>3` version you observe the same behaviour:

```
In[49]:
df[df>3]

Out[49]: 
     0   1    2
0  NaN NaN  NaN
1  4.0 NaN  6.0
```

Also just to show this has nothing to do with `numpy`, using pandas `isnull` gives the same result:

```
In[50]:
df[df.isnull()]

Out[50]: 
    0   1   2
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Yes! It explains all ! Thanks!